# undocumented fp query param in Google search URL

Tags: google-search

The [Search Protocol Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/52/xml_reference.html) doesn't mention anything about fp param. Yet, it seems to show up sometimes.  Does anyone know what it does?

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Yes.  

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=active&q=rent+a+car&fp=zA38ZNZUnYc

Note that this isn't really a query param, it's an anchor ref which makes me think Goog is using it from Javascript to interact with the servers.

Comment: I don't know, but I just saw an example, too... given other context, I somehow imagine it to be an affiliates program or something?  This is entirely speculation on my part, based on the context in which I saw a link, so I'm not treating it as an answer, but maybe it can lead to one.  More info on a now-officially-defunct affiliate program: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Affiliate_Network and/or http://www.google.com/ads/affiliatenetwork/  -- I didn't find info on fp specifically, though (but also didn't dig very deep)